# Rails dependent destroy all

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.1

How do I generate a delete cascade in Rails?

I have these models:

```
class UploadFile < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :purchases, dependent: :delete_all
end

class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :purchasers,   dependent: :delete_all
    has_many :items,        dependent: :delete_all
    has_many :merchants,    dependent: :delete_all

    has_one :upload_file
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
end 

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
end 

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

When I delete `upload_file` only the Purchase's data will be destroyed. The rest still exist in the DB.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `destroy_all` here not `delete_all`.

From the [api dock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/destroy_all/class):

> **destroy_all(conditions = nil) public**
>
> Destroys the records matching conditions by instantiating each record
>   and calling its destroy method. Each object’s callbacks are executed
>   (including :dependent association options and
>   before_destroy/after_destroy Observer methods).